# Add javascript fallback for input type="date" where browser support is not available

Tags: javascript, html, date, input, datepicker

Adding type date to input fields now produces a browser based date picker. (Where supported).

```
<input type="date"></input>
```

[image]

This is fantasic for touch devies however...

When browsing with the meat of the market: firefox and internet explorer, type date is not supported.

---

## QUESTION

How to use input `type="date"` and fallback to a javascript date picker when support is not available?

Currently I cant seem to get the best of both worlds without producing both date pickers simultaneously.

Comment: Browsers that don’t support `type=date` should report the type as the default `text` when it’s queried via JS …

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at this polyfill :

https://github.com/chemerisuk/better-dateinput-polyfill

Comment: Fallback script and type detector all in one. The date picker is actually smaller and better than the one I had to start with. Many thanks.

Comment: But with a lot of dependencies. JQuery is not enough.

Answer (score 13):

You should look into using [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) which uses JS to work out what features the current browser has.  In the below example you can serve another datepicker if this browser isn't compatible:

```
<script src="modernizr.js"></script>
<script>Modernizr.load({
  test: Modernizr.inputtypes.date,
  nope: ['http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.min.js', 'jquery-ui.css'],
  complete: function () {
    $('input[type=date]').datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    }); 
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is great and would solve the issue. However I am strict about using excess code if it can be avoided. The overhead on this is a lot for what I want to achieve. Is it possible to do a compatibility check just for this one feature.

Comment: If you only want to use YepNope with Modernizr.load you can just use that. http://modernizr.com/download/#-load I tend to use Modernizr for feature detection quite a lot for other types of input, CSS transforms and html5shiv.  It's almost a pre-requisit for my builds so I'd give a second thought to including more of it's feature detection too :)

Comment: Thanks @richieahb. I will take a deeper look at it.

Comment: You will also need the input detection in the modernizr bundle which you can find in this package http://modernizr.com/download/#-inputtypes-load and it's only 6kb.

Comment: Note that the 'nope' is now deprecated and won't work to conditionally load scripts etc. You will now have to use jQuery or something else to load the scripts (or always load them if you don't care about slower pages).